# Execution Time of a program

Tags: cpu-architecture

Assuming that the CPI of a program is 1.5 and the clock period is 500ns. What is the execution time?.

What is the execution time?.

I think that the execution time is the time the program takes to execute 1 instruction like latency.

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to know the execution time of a program just by looking at the CPI and the clock period. CPI gives the average number of cycles it takes to execute an instruction. If you executed 1 billion instructions, or 1 million instructions you can still have the same CPI. So, without knowing the number of instructions that are executed there is no way you can infer the execution time. If you had the number of instructions, the execution time would be:

> t_execution = (Clock period) x CPI x (Number of executed instructions)

.